# Burn Windows 8 image to a DVD using linux

Tags: linux, windows-8, dvd, iso-image, burning

I dont know why, but when i try to boot Windows 8 install from flashdisk, i get stuck on logo, nothing else happens. So, i've got an idea, that will be better burn iso to a DVD. I tried to burn that with Xfburn, that i have native in my distro, but the dvd was unusable, so i write on it "Linux sux" and threw it out of the Window. Now i have only 3 more dvds left.
How can i burn on dvd windows iso using linux?

Comment: You can use brasero, it has always worked for me, even windows disks. As long as the file is an .iso it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 image has UDF filesystem.

Try using [K3b](http://www.k3b.org/) to burn ISO. It has UDF support.

If you want to burn image on USB drive read [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/487970/269282).

Answer (score 1):

The filesystem is already in the image file.
So it does not matter whether UDF, ISO 9660 or something else.

Also, the pointers for the boot firmware have to be in the image.

For flash drive this would be MBR and/or GPT partition entries
which lead BIOS or UEFI to the first program in the boot chain.
You may see these by inspecting the image file by partition
editors like fdisk (for MBR) and gdisk (for GPT).

For DVD, there has to be El Torito: boot record, catalog, one
or more boot images.
You may see this by programs like isoinfo or xorriso:

```
imagefile=...path.to.win8.file...

isoinfo -d -i $imagefile
```

should report about a "Eltorito validation header".

```
xorriso -indev $imagefile -toc
```

should report about "Boot record  :", "Boot catalog :", and
"Boot image   : ...".

Now if the image has El Torito equipment it should boot from DVD.
Make sure to burn it as single preformatted image, and not as
"data composition" or "project" where you could put more than one
file onto DVD.

Command line programs for burning to DVD:

```
growisofs -dvd-compat -Z /dev/sr0=$imagefile

xorriso -as cdrecord -v dev=/dev/sr0 -eject $imagefile
```

The program growisofs is normally used by K3b.
xorriso uses the same libburn as does Xfburn.